# Setting CameraType to Scriptable does not fix camera to a location

Tags: roblox

How do I make the camera in a roblox game fixed?

It seems like if I add this LocalScript

[image: workspace treeview highlighting the LocalScript]

that reads

```lua
local cam = workspace.CurrentCamera 

cam.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable
```

then, the effects are overridden by some script, because when I move the player, the camera moves.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you do this before the character loads in then it messes up. This is because character spawning includes setting the CurrentCamera property to the default value.
You should avoid this by using a repeat until workspace.CurrentCamera.CameraType ~= Enum... then set it to your desired value.

(Basically): Your doing it before the character loads, the character loads and sets it to default value.

Comment: Would it be possible to add code to the answer? Thanks a lot!